# Cocoa NSView: Making circles but they are getting cropped

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsbezierpath

the outer edges of my circle at each point of the compass are getting cropped (presumably by the rect frame). How do I get the circle to display within the frame? (This is getting created from a button click):

In my AppController.m

```
#import "AppController.h"
#import "MakeCircle.h"

@implementation AppController

- (IBAction)makeCircle:(id)sender {

     MakeCircle* newCircle = [[MakeCircle alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
     [[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] contentView] addSubview:newCircle];

     [newCircle release];
}

@end
```

In my MakeCircle.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {

     [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

     [[NSColor blackColor] setStroke];

     // Create our circle path
     NSBezierPath* circlePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
     [circlePath appendBezierPathWithOvalInRect: rect];

     //give the line some thickness
     [circlePath setLineWidth:4];

     // Outline and fill the path
     [circlePath stroke];


  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you see only half of the edge, right? You can calculate the half of the thickness of the edge and subtract that from the rectangle:

```
#define STROKE_COLOR    ([NSColor blackColor])
#define STROKE_WIDTH    (4.0)
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSBezierPath *path;
    NSRect rectangle;

    /* Calculate rectangle */
    rectangle = [self bounds];
    rectangle.origin.x += STROKE_WIDTH / 2.0;
    rectangle.origin.y += STROKE_WIDTH / 2.0;
    rectangle.size.width -= STROKE_WIDTH / 2.0;
    rectangle.size.height -= STROKE_WIDTH / 2.0;
    path = [NSBezierPath path];
    [path appendBezierPathWithOvalInRect:rectangle];
    [path setLineWidth:STROKE_WIDTH];
    [STROKE_COLOR setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
```

I have no Mac at the moment, so I can't test it, but I think it should solve your problem.

Als don't call `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]`. The method is used when you want to redraw your whole NSView, and calling it from the drawing method is a little bit recursive. That's why I'm surprised your code actually draws something.

And I have another tip: `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow]` is actually the same as `[NSApp mainWindow]`. `NSApp` is a global variable containing the main application.

Hope it helps,
ief2

Comment: thanks, I kind of figured out the same thing - there's no method/property to tell cocoa where to draw the stroke similar to what you can do in Photoshop - stroke inside, center, outside? -       and thanks for the NSApp tip...

Comment: I changed these two lines from:                                                                  rectangle.size.width -= STROKE_WIDTH/2;
    rectangle.size.height -= STROKE_WIDTH/2;                        
to                                                                   rectangle.size.width -= STROKE_WIDTH;
 rectangle.size.height -= STROKE_WIDTH;